# getting an argument out of range error for tickle

Tags: ruby, chronic

From the docs: https://github.com/yb66/tickle

`Tickle.parse('day')
 #=> {:next=>2010-05-10 20:57:36 -0400, :expression=>"day", :starting=>2010-05-09 20:57:36 -0400, :until=>nil}`

My console:

`2.2.1 :013 > Tickle.parse('day')
ArgumentError: argument out of range`

Was working fine, now failing.  I am unclear how to fix this.

Full stack trace:

```
ArgumentError: argument out of range
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tickle-0.1.7/lib/tickle.rb:80:in `local'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tickle-0.1.7/lib/tickle.rb:80:in `bump'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tickle-0.1.7/lib/tickle/handler.rb:27:in `guess_unit_types'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tickle-0.1.7/lib/tickle/handler.rb:11:in `guess'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tickle-0.1.7/lib/tickle/tickle.rb:90:in `parse'
    from (irb):13
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/exe/bundle:35:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bundler-1.15.1/exe/bundle:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'2.2.1 :014 >
```

Comment: I can't reproduce with your version of ruby & tickle.

Comment: Looks like an old bug, that was fixed. The old versions of `tickle` has a implementation of `Numerizer` module. The latest version uses a third-party gem. Is it possible to update the gem to a more recent version?

Comment: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/tickle-0.1.7

Comment: Is this the latest: 2.0.0.rc1 - November 07, 2015 (29